# JMeter distributed test

Tags: testing, jmeter, distributed

I have configured 5 servers and  run distributed tests with JMeter.  But if  one of these servers is down, the entire test does not start.  Is there any way to start the tests only  with the available servers? 
Let's say  i have  servers A,B,C,D,E .  Before  i start the test ,  lets say  server A  stops. Is it  possible  for  jmeter  to start the distributed test and continue  with the available servers? Thx
tolga

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to ping them all before starting the test and write only those responding into the config file.

AFAIK JMeter simply expects the configured load generators to be online and to work.